# Indexing the difference between two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, index

Is there a way to optimize/index a query that sorts the difference between two columns.  I have a modest sized table of 5 million rows that I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT pk_column, column_x, column_y, column_x-column_y 
FROM table_a 
ORDER BY column_x-column_y DESC
```

This particular query takes about 2 seconds, however this ORDER BY seems to create a fairly large bottleneck in more complex queries.

Comment: What are your indexes?  A covering index on `pk_column` including `column_x` and `column_y` should be fine.  Since there are no filters on your query, you're stuck doing a scan, even if you can index on the difference of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. Be sure and let us know if my suggestion works for you - don't [dine and dash](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)! :-). p.s. almost forgot, welcome to the forums.

Comment: I tested with and without a covering index and didn't really notice much of a performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You could try MariaDB which supports [virtual columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/virtual-columns/).

> Indexes are partially supported. Virtual columns do not support
>   primary keys and indexes can only be based on PERSISTENT virtual
>   columns. PERSISTENT columns can be part of a foreign key and can be
>   referenced by foreign keys, but ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON UPDATE SET NULL,
>   ON DELETE SET NULL are not allowed.

You could simulate this through your INSERTs or via TRIGGERs (better IMHO) and index the simulated virtual column. Then test to see does that resolve your issue (or at least improve it).

[EDIT in response to the OP's comment]

Yes, indeed, I thought that MariaDB would be a "bridge too far". I really included it for completeness. MariaDB is a drop-in replacement up and including 5.5 (in MariaDB terms). AFAICS, the 10 series is still compatible (it's like MySQL with bits added, but the divergence will only widen in the future AIUI.

The advantage of using a persisten column is that the persistent column can be indexed whereas the virtual one can't according to the docco that I quoted.

Has the idea of "simulated" virtual columns worked for you?

Comment: Changing DBMS seems like a bit of an endeavor, though MariaDB is probably an easier switch from MySQL given their common roots.  What is the advantage of using a persistent virtual column rather than just creating an actual column?

Comment: The advantage of the virtual column is that it is all managed for you as part of the database's operations (if it is built-in) or your triggers (if you need to implement it that way). You don't have to enforce it in every piece of code that might ever insert or update that table making it far less likely that integrity issues will develop due to bugs.